# How to merge multiple arrays in foreach loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

How to merge multiple arrays in foreach loop. I'm trying to merge all 3 `imageData` arrays in one single array. Please tell if I missed anything from following method.

```
  const imageArray = [
      {
        imageData: [
          'https://via.placeholder.com/50',
          'https://via.placeholder.com/60'
        ],
      },
      {
        imageData: [
          'https://via.placeholder.com/100'
        ],
      },
      {
        imageData: [
          'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
        ],
     }
  ];

  processImage() {
    imageArray.forEach((element) => {
      const imageCollection = [...element.imageData];
      console.log(imageCollection);
      // Expected result 
      //['https://via.placeholder.com/50', 'https://via.placeholder.com/60', 'https://via.placeholder.com/100', https://via.placeholder.com/150]
    });
  }
```

Comment: `imageArray.reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c.imageData), []);`, readable O(n²) solution for not overly large datasets.

Comment: You're redefining `imageCollection` in every loop.

Comment: you're looking for [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: Ngl even though it was not ES6 only (`flatMap` came later), i liked that solution the most, because it was very readable, and hopefully O(n) (i'd assume engines optimize that much). My glass ball tells me, that being overly specific on ES6 is not the intention anyways.

Comment: I certainly didn't mean to have @Barmar delete his answer; I actually upvoted it. I think that people are too quick to tag things with ES versions. Unless you're asking a question *about* the version, or want answers to only use a specific version, there's no reason to tag a question with a version.

Comment: People still assume it's a binary decision between pre-es6 and es6+, old browsers, and new, and use "es6" as "yeah modern is fine". However, we are now at ES2021, and things changed. Tbh, even if the target was specifically ES6, using something like babel, and writing ES2021, would usually be the correct solution anyways.

Answer (score 5):

You declare the new imageCollection inside the loop.. Thus you create a new array each iteration...

Do it outside and use `imageCollection.push(...element.imageData)` inside forEach loop

Comment: right sorry forgot the spread operator. Edited answere

Answer (score 5):

Your array needs to be outside the `forEach` loop so it is accessible after the `forEach` is completed.

```js
const imageArray = [
  {
    imageData: [
      'https://via.placeholder.com/50',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/60'
    ]
  },
  {
    imageData: ['https://via.placeholder.com/100']
  },
  {
    imageData: ['https://via.placeholder.com/150']
  }
];

const processImage = function (imageArray) {
  const imageCollection = [];
  imageArray.forEach(element => {
    imageCollection.push(...element.imageData);
  });
  return imageCollection;
};
```

Expected result for `processImage(imageArray)`

```js
[
  'https://via.placeholder.com/50',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/60',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/100',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign `imageCollection` outside of the `forEach` (but still inside of `processImage()`). Then in the redefinition of `imageCollection` inside of the `forEach`, spread the contents of each previous `imageCollection` array, followed by the contents of `element.imageData`. Like so:

```
//...
processImage() {
  let imageCollection = [];
  imageArray.forEach((element) => {
    imageCollection = [...imageCollection, ...element.imageData];
//...
```

### Full Code for Your Context

```
const imageArray = [
    {
      imageData: [
        'https://via.placeholder.com/50',
        'https://via.placeholder.com/60'
      ],
    },
    {
      imageData: [
        'https://via.placeholder.com/100'
      ],
    },
    {
      imageData: [
        'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
      ],
    }
];

processImage() {
  let imageCollection = [];
  imageArray.forEach((element) => {
    imageCollection = [...imageCollection, ...element.imageData];
    console.log(imageCollection);
    // Expected result 
    //['https://via.placeholder.com/50', 'https://via.placeholder.com/60', 'https://via.placeholder.com/100', https://via.placeholder.com/150]
  });
  console.log('ImageCollection',imageCollection);
}
```

### Full Code for Running Outside of Your Context

```
const imageArray = [
    {
      imageData: [
        'https://via.placeholder.com/50',
        'https://via.placeholder.com/60'
      ],
    },
    {
      imageData: [
        'https://via.placeholder.com/100'
      ],
    },
    {
      imageData: [
        'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
      ],
    }
];

function processImage() {
  let imageCollection = [];
  imageArray.forEach((element) => {
    imageCollection = [...imageCollection, ...element.imageData];
    console.log(imageCollection);
    // Expected result 
    //['https://via.placeholder.com/50', 'https://via.placeholder.com/60', 'https://via.placeholder.com/100', https://via.placeholder.com/150]
  });
  console.log('ImageCollect',imageCollection);
}

processImage();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,foreach in the object imageData, and saving each value in an array using another Foreach.

```
    let newImageData = []

    imageArray.forEach((data)=>{

       const imageDataArray = data.imageData
       imageDataArray.forEach(link => {
        newImageData.push(link)
       });
      

  })
  
  const NewImageArray = {imageData:newImageData}
  console.log(NewImageArray)
```

Comment: Why use both `map` and `forEach` when the task can be accomplished with one of them? Additionally you did not define a return statement in your `map`. This will yield an error.

Comment: i was mapping without create a new object with the return, but u are right, better a simple foreach instead. is a aproach, i think is most readable